# TypeScript incremental parser implementation

Tags: typescript, parsing

I was recently studying the TypeScript parser in order to find out how a pretty recursive descent parser could be made incremental.

If you look at the implementation of the incremental re-parsing of a source-file in TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/parser.ts#L7213, it seems to be restarting from the beginning. All statements get re-parsed. It seems that when incremental parsing: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/parser.ts#L1714 allows to lookup existing nodes in the old-tree for re-use.

If I'm reading the source correct, incremental parsing still parses the whole file. It just lookups nodes from the old tree, instead of re-creating new ones when possible.

My question: why does the incremental parser start from the beginning?
Isn't it more logical in an incremental context to walk the parsetree until the "damaged" part and re-start parsing from there? I.e. you locate the node, initialize your scanner from there and start a re-parse with the appropiate parse function?

Comment: I think it is difficult to get to predict how much of the tree changes due to a single edit. The strategy of reusing the node achieves good perf as probably allocating new memory and garbage collection of old nodes would be the dominating perf issue not the parsing itself, but this is more an educated guess than based on metrics or insider info.